# How to add to mongodb, MERN app validation failed error

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, mern

I'm trying to learn the MERN stack, I'm trying to create a simple shopping list app.

I have a simple api to get, post and delete items, this all works using Postman when testing the api.

Locally the get works and I can get items from the db.

When I try to add to the db I get this error.

```
(node:28550) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: item validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.
[0]     at new ValidationError (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/merntest-redux-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:30:11)
[0]     at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/merntest-redux-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2080:32)
[0]     at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/merntest-redux-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1943:17)
[0]     at /Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/merntest-redux-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:933:9
[0]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[0] (node:28550) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
[0] (node:28550) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

As the api works in postman I think it must be something to do the redux I'm using.

ShoppingList js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getItems, deleteItem, addItem} from '../actions/itemActions';

class ShoppingList extends Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getItems()
  }

  onDeleteClick = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteItem(id);
  }

  render(){

    const {items} = this.props.item

    return(
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            const name = prompt('New Item')

            if(name){
              this.props.addItem(name)
            }
          }}
        >
          Add Item
        </button>
        <ul>
          {items.map(({id,name}) =>{
            return(
              <li key={id}>
                <button
                  onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, id)}
                >
                  &times;
                </button>
                {name}
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps, {getItems, deleteItem, addItem})(ShoppingList)
```

itemActions

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING} from '../actions/types';

export const getItems = () => dispatch =>{
  dispatch(setItemsLaoding());
  axios
    .get('/api/items')
    .then(res => 
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ITEMS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
}

export const addItem = (name) => dispatch =>{
  axios 
    .post('/api/items', name)
    .then(res => 
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_ITEM,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
}

export const deleteItem = (id) =>{
  return{
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    payload: id
  }
}

export const setItemsLaoding = () => {
  return{
    type: ITEMS_LOADING
  }
}
```

itemReducer.js

```
import {GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return{
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
        loading:false
      }
    case DELETE_ITEM:
      return{
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)
      }  
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return{
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, { name: action.payload}]
      }  
    case ITEMS_LOADING:
      return{
        ...state,
        loading:true
      }
    default:
      return state  
  }
}
```

models/Item.js (mongoose model)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name:{
    type: 'String',
    required: true 
  },
  Date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

routes/api/items.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Item = require('../../models/Item');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Item.find()
        .then(items => res.json(items))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newItem = new Item({
        name: req.body.name
    })
    newItem
        .save()
        .then(item => res.json(item))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) =>{
    Item.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({success:true})))
        .catch(err => err.status(404).json({success:false}))
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I did some debugging and here is the problem, you are sending the item name as the key with no value so the API cannot understand it.

Change this code:

```
export const addItem = (name) => dispatch =>{
  axios 
    .post('/api/items', name)
    .then(res => 
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_ITEM,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
}
```

to this code:

```
export const addItem = name => dispatch => {
  const req = {
    name,
  };

  axios.post('/api/items', req).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_ITEM,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Thats don't it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding this code to `routes/api/items.js`:

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```